# BeautifulSoup tag has hyperlink

Tags: html, tags, beautifulsoup, urllib2

Is there a method or attribute of a BeautifulSoup.Tag that gets an underlying URL hyperlink the element has? My code below ends with a list of tags, and each of these tags has a URL tied to them if I inspect the Element in Google Chrome Developer.

Here's my python code to get the tag

```
import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib2 as ul

main_site = 'https://www.uinet.com/wps/portal/uinet/about/doing%20business%20with%20ui/power%20procurement/active%20rfps/public%20disclosure/!ut/p/a1/vVJNc4IwFPwruXh0EsDwcWRsx6HjF2pb4OIEEjAOBISg_fmNTDvq2Jb20tzee_s22d3ACAYwEuTIMyJ5KUh-riNzO114k9nY8lzvxcfIG3m6v1iNNYSwAoQ3gLU5UoBH19p4czTR9L79VxjBKBGykjsYtlwwCYaAxGUrQcsHqOsM0KVBSy4yELeNGjQNOHG56_pVeWI1qOoyaWtWMHFeSiQ_MlCnVaPmbZzzBFDeJHnZKMz53opkjLKGZ6KrEk5hqGFKbcNGI8QoobYWE-qkxDGwiR2WWp-K0TfHRX2Kn35hqV7PxrPs_EC5G3KRljD4WjgM7oTD4Eq4mt8JV_x8fzhErjK-FJK9qZV_db7LvOfXdIAfTA5VCtYVw8J5UAwb3_NtS0MrBNeXSI2YGhb7iBRjFhPTuom0h0y_Juv9Hz1k2p_IquK5sPfpFOfZcpqul0Wxnc-HJHwH-3oADQ!!/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/'

html = ul.urlopen(main_site).read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html)

tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    str_tag = tag.text
    if str_tag.endswith('Redacted Bid Sheets'):
       #this is where I want to do something like ul.urlopen(tag url)
```

Hovering over any of the tags like below in Chrome Developer shows the HTML below it

`<a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FApril%2B19%252C%2B%2B2016%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">A`

https://www.uinet.com/wps/portal/uinet/about/doing%20business%20with%20ui/power%20procurement/active%20rfps/public%20disclosure/april%2019%2C%20%202016%20-%20redacted%20bid%20sheets/!ut/p/a1/zVLLTsMwEPwVX7gR2Xk4To5VQVVQS1Uo0OaCkthJXSVOiJ3y-Hq2ERLlmXLDt92ZHa9mB8d4hWOV7GSRGFmrpNzXsX8_nUeT2ZhFo-h2QUnkRc5ifjW2CaFAWH8gXPseEM5HbBldkontDM3f4RjHmTKN2eB1J5UwyEJJWncGdfKE9J0T8t7gtVQFSjsNgNboUZpN32_qR9Gipq2zrhWVUPuhzMidQG3eaMC7tJQZ4lJnZa2BA3jTyhLZ4SlCDrF9-LcVHIYER6nkSG-EMHq_XpMUggstC9VXmeR4TTIeernjWcwm1PJczq0gpMTKuPC5TRlnafBmDvnhjciQORdHuO-0s_Gs2C9pNpZUeY1X33uEV188wqsDjwD_7BHgR3kEa8jtw0M8glPWyognUP6Pt-zDNhDXnvDLydZwU3agMA_PQGG5iBYBROGK4Ov3kLgpd5kIiEdgGUpFmvgsT0KX-jQUOaNDYs6h2FGJGxC0_yzYVDdVsM2ntCzOnl2ypc3uZZlX1Ss9wOgH/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/

I'm fairly a novice in both Python and HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the no longer maintained version of BeautifulSoup3, you need to upgrade to bs4, the following code will find all the links you want using a css selector looking for the href's ending in the string you are looking for:

```
In [4]: import requests
   ...: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   ...: main_site = 'https://www.uinet.com/wps/portal/uinet/about/doing%20busine
   ...: ss%20with%20ui/power%20procurement/active%20rfps/public%20disclosure/!ut
   ...: /p/a1/vVJNc4IwFPwruXh0EsDwcWRsx6HjF2pb4OIEEjAOBISg_fmNTDvq2Jb20tzee_s22d
   ...: 3ACAYwEuTIMyJ5KUh-riNzO114k9nY8lzvxcfIG3m6v1iNNYSwAoQ3gLU5UoBH19p4czTR9L
   ...: 79VxjBKBGykjsYtlwwCYaAxGUrQcsHqOsM0KVBSy4yELeNGjQNOHG56_pVeWI1qOoyaWtWMH
   ...: FeSiQ_MlCnVaPmbZzzBFDeJHnZKMz53opkjLKGZ6KrEk5hqGFKbcNGI8QoobYWE-qkxDGwiR
   ...: 2WWp-K0TfHRX2Kn35hqV7PxrPs_EC5G3KRljD4WjgM7oTD4Eq4mt8JV_x8fzhErjK-FJK9qZ
   ...: V_db7LvOfXdIAfTA5VCtYVw8J5UAwb3_NtS0MrBNeXSI2YGhb7iBRjFhPTuom0h0y_Juv9Hz
   ...: 1k2p_IquK5sPfpFOfZcpqul0Wxnc-HJHwH-3oADQ!!/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/'
   ...: 
   ...: html = requests.get(main_site).content
   ...: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
   ...: print(soup.select("a[href$=Redacted%2BBid%2BSheets]"))
   ...: 

   [<a href="?1dmy¤t=true&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FApril%2B19%252C%2B%2B2016%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">April 19,  2016 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy¤t=true&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FFebruary%2B2%2B%2B2016%2B%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">February 2,  2016 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy¤t=true&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FOctober%2B20%2B2015%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">October 20, 2015 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy¤t=true&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FFebruary%2B2%252C%2B2016%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">February 2, 2016 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy¤t=true&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FJuly%2B28%252C%2B2015%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">July 28, 2015 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy¤t=true&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FApril%2B21%252C%2B2015%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">April 21, 2015 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy¤t=true&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FFebruary%2B10%2B2015%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">February 10, 2015 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy¤t=true&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FOctober%2B21%252C%2B2014-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">October 21, 2014- Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy¤t=true&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FJuly%2B22%252C%2B2014%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">July 22, 2014 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy¤t=true&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FApril%2B22%252C%2B2014%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">April 22, 2014 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy¤t=true&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FJanuary%2B28%2B2014%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">January 28, 2014 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy¤t=true&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FOctober%2B22%2B2013%2B%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">October 22, 2013 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FApril%2B19%252C%2B%2B2016%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">April 19,  2016 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FFebruary%2B2%2B%2B2016%2B%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">February 2,  2016 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FOctober%2B20%2B2015%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">October 20, 2015 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FFebruary%2B2%252C%2B2016%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">February 2, 2016 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FJuly%2B28%252C%2B2015%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">July 28, 2015 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FApril%2B21%252C%2B2015%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">April 21, 2015 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FFebruary%2B10%2B2015%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">February 10, 2015 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FOctober%2B21%252C%2B2014-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">October 21, 2014- Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FJuly%2B22%252C%2B2014%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">July 22, 2014 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FApril%2B22%252C%2B2014%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">April 22, 2014 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FJanuary%2B28%2B2014%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">January 28, 2014 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FOctober%2B22%2B2013%2B%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">October 22, 2013 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FSeptember%2B10%2B2013%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">September 10, 2013 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FJuly%2B16%2B2013%2B%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">July 16, 2013 – Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FApril%2B23%2B2013%2B%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">April 23, 2013 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FJanuary%2B29%2B2013%2B%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">January 29, 2013 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FOctober%2B23%252C%2B2012%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">October 23, 2012 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FJuly%2B24%252C%2B2012%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">July 24, 2012 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FApril%2B24%252C%2B2012%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">April 24, 2012 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>, <a href="?1dmy&amp;urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FFebruary%2B7%252C%2B2012%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets">February 7, 2012 - Redacted Bid Sheets</a>]
```

To extract the hrefs:

```
In [5]: [a["href"] for a in soup.select("a[href$=Redacted%2BBid%2BSheets]")]
Out[5]: 
['?1dmy¤t=true&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FApril%2B19%252C%2B%2B2016%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy¤t=true&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FFebruary%2B2%2B%2B2016%2B%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy¤t=true&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FOctober%2B20%2B2015%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy¤t=true&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FFebruary%2B2%252C%2B2016%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy¤t=true&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FJuly%2B28%252C%2B2015%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy¤t=true&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FApril%2B21%252C%2B2015%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy¤t=true&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FFebruary%2B10%2B2015%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy¤t=true&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FOctober%2B21%252C%2B2014-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy¤t=true&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FJuly%2B22%252C%2B2014%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy¤t=true&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FApril%2B22%252C%2B2014%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy¤t=true&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FJanuary%2B28%2B2014%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy¤t=true&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FOctober%2B22%2B2013%2B%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FApril%2B19%252C%2B%2B2016%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FFebruary%2B2%2B%2B2016%2B%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FOctober%2B20%2B2015%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FFebruary%2B2%252C%2B2016%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FJuly%2B28%252C%2B2015%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FApril%2B21%252C%2B2015%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FFebruary%2B10%2B2015%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FOctober%2B21%252C%2B2014-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FJuly%2B22%252C%2B2014%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FApril%2B22%252C%2B2014%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FJanuary%2B28%2B2014%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FOctober%2B22%2B2013%2B%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FSeptember%2B10%2B2013%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FJuly%2B16%2B2013%2B%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FApril%2B23%2B2013%2B%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FJanuary%2B29%2B2013%2B%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FOctober%2B23%252C%2B2012%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FJuly%2B24%252C%2B2012%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FApril%2B24%252C%2B2012%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets',
 '?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a%2FUINet%2B-%2BAbout%2BUI%2FUINet%2FAbout%2BUI%2FDoing%2BBusiness%2Bwith%2BUI%2FPower%2BProcurement%2FActive%2BRFPs%2FPublic%2BDisclosure%2FFebruary%2B7%252C%2B2012%2B-%2BRedacted%2BBid%2BSheets']
```